# Displaying board coordinates as ASCII board

Tags: java, coordinates

I currently have a 1D array of board coordinates (eg ["B1","D1","F1","H1","E8"] used for a board game. I have initialised my array 'positions' to be the above values, but this could be anything during anytime of the game. The length of this array changes depending on the user given dimension. I want to read this information and print the following all in one string. Every array element represents X, except for the final element which is Y.

```
    ABCDEFGH
  1 .X.X.X.X 1
  2 ........ 2
  3 ........ 3
  4 ........ 4
  5 ........ 5
  6 ........ 6
  7 ........ 7
  8 ....Y... 8
    ABCDEFGH
```

As it is all one string, I believe I should be using stringbuilder, but I am struggling to find the correct angle to be taken. This would be easier creating a class, but I want to avoid creating any new classes. I have tried printing the full board without the marked locations but this proved difficult to then go in and change the given coordinate to the required X/Y

UPDATE: I now have the coordinates converted to their integer values. So ["B1","D1","F1","H1","E8"] has been converted to [2,1,4,1,6,1,8,8]

Comment: Why do you want to avoid creating new classes?  Grouping elements into a class is one easy way to reduce the complexity of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Try reading them into a `char[][]` array and then find a way to display that.

Comment: It is just part of the specifications of writing this that it should be done creating no new classes.

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and created a runnable example of what you're asking for.  I had to make a few assumptions about your class.

Here's the output.

```
   ABCDEFGH
 1 .X.X.X.X  1
 2 ........  2
 3 ........  3
 4 ........  4
 5 ........  5
 6 ........  6
 7 ........  7
 8 ....Y...  8
   ABCDEFGH
```

Here's the runnable example.  I'll explain my reasoning after the code.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class GameBoard {

    private static String[] playerXCoordinates = 
        {"B1", "D1", "F1", "H1"};

    private static String[] playerYCoordinates = 
        {"E8"};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GameBoard gameBoard = new GameBoard(8, 8);
        gameBoard.setPlayersX(playerXCoordinates);
        gameBoard.setPlayersY(playerYCoordinates);
        System.out.println(gameBoard.toString());
    }

    private int width, height;

    private List<String> playersX;
    private List<String> playersY;

    public GameBoard(int width, int height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.playersX = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.playersY = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    public void setPlayersX(String[] players) {
        for (int i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
            playersX.add(players[i]);
        }
    }

    public void setPlayersY(String[] players) {
        for (int i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
            playersY.add(players[i]);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String newLine = System.lineSeparator();
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append(createAlphaLine());
        builder.append(newLine);
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
            builder.append(createBoardLine(i + 1));
            builder.append(newLine);
        }
        builder.append(createAlphaLine());
        return builder.toString();
    }

    private StringBuilder createAlphaLine() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("   ");
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
            char c = (char) (i + 'A');
            builder.append(c);
        }
        return builder;
    }

    private StringBuilder createBoardLine(int index) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append(String.format("%2d", index));
        builder.append(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
            char c = (char) (i + 'A');
            String s = Character.toString(c) + index;
            if (playersX.contains(s)) {
                builder.append("X");
            } else if (playersY.contains(s)) {
                builder.append("Y");
            } else {
                builder.append(".");
            }
        }
        builder.append(" ");
        builder.append(String.format("%2d", index));
        return builder;
    }

}
```

I created this class one method at a time.

First, I assumed certain inputs into the class.  You weren't very clear about the class inputs.

Next, I built the `toString` method one part at a time.

I did the alphabet rows first.  Then, when that part of the code worked, I worked on the board rows.  First, I did the row numbers.  Finally, I checked the `Lists` to determine which character to print.

Divide and conquer.  Usually, you do it with classes.  In this case, I did it with methods.  Code one method at a time, and test each method.

Divide and conquer.

Edited to add:  Just for fun, here's the 26 X 26 board output.

```
   ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
 1 .X.X.X.X..................  1
 2 ..........................  2
 3 ..........................  3
 4 ..........................  4
 5 ..........................  5
 6 ..........................  6
 7 ..........................  7
 8 ....Y.....................  8
 9 ..........................  9
10 .......................... 10
11 .......................... 11
12 .......................... 12
13 .......................... 13
14 .......................... 14
15 .......................... 15
16 .......................... 16
17 .......................... 17
18 .......................... 18
19 .......................... 19
20 .......................... 20
21 .......................... 21
22 .......................... 22
23 .......................... 23
24 .......................... 24
25 .......................... 25
26 .......................... 26
   ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```